# how to get start and end point of street between adjacency streets

Tags: python, geolocation, maps, coordinates

https://prnt.sc/UvVbaDAhI1oY This is the dataset of my data.
I have following street name and two adjacency streets. I want to find the coordinates like start point of one adjacency to end point of another adjacency streets. I have coordinates of the main street as well. Can anyone guide me how to do find the start and end points?

Comment: You'll probably need your source data in a file (as text) or perhaps in a database rather than as an image. You'll also need to write some code

Comment: yes i have as csv file. can you guide me with further information. i'm beginner and trying lots of things without proper direction so i'm kind of lost

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html